# javascript global variable not accessible where it should be!

Tags: javascript, jquery

consider the code

```
$(function(){
     $.ajax({
        url:'cartProcess.php',
        data:{pname:prod, pqty:qty},
        type:'GET',
        dataType:'json',
        success:function(json){
                var k = eval(json);
                var n = k[0].Name;
                var q = k[0].Quantity;
                var t = k[0].Total;
            },
        complete:{          
            $('input.newQty').live('change', function(){
            alert(t/q);     
            });
                 }

  });   
});
```

firebug gives an error saying t is not defined. 
How do i use these variables globally?

Comment: t is defined in the success function, which is out of scope of the function inside the callback of the live(); You could define t somewhere else or change the structure of your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
$(function(){
     var q = 0;
     var t = 0;

     $.ajax({
        url:'cartProcess.php',
        data:{pname:prod, pqty:qty},
        type:'GET',
        dataType:'json',
        success:function(json){
                var k = eval(json);
                var n = k[0].Name;
                q = k[0].Quantity;
                t = k[0].Total;
        },
        complete:{          
            $('input.newQty').live('change', function(){
                alert(t/q);     
            });
        }
  });   
});
```

Comment: thank you!! that worked..i need to brush up my scope knowledge1!

Comment: i wud like to do that asap but SO doesn't let me do that!! says you can accept this answer in 49 secs!!

Answer (score 0):

Javascript variables are always in the scope of the function they are declared in. As far as the complete function is concerned, t does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

You have this variable in two different scopes. change it like this

```
 $(function(){
         var k ,t;
         $.ajax({
            url:'cartProcess.php',
            data:{pname:prod, pqty:qty},
            type:'GET',
            dataType:'json',
            success:function(json){
                    k = eval(json);
                    var n = k[0].Name;
                    var q = k[0].Quantity;
                    t = k[0].Total;
                },
            complete:{          
                $('input.newQty').live('change', function(){
                alert(t/q);     
                });
                     }

      });   
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You're defining the local variable `t` inside the `success` function - it will not be visible in the `complete` function. Try defining them inside the "root" function before the `$.ajax(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

Your variables are **local** to your success function. You should move your `.live` code into the success function most probably.

Also you don't need:

```
eval(json);
```

You've already set the dataType as json, so it should automatically be available as a json object.